# Excel: IF statement with Dates

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I am trying to have excel look at a cell(M2), identify which year is in the date and then fill my current cell(N2) with that year.  Here is my current code below, which doesn't work.

=if(M2 = Year(2017),"2017",if(M2 = Year(2018),"2018",if(M2 = Year(2019),"2019", "Before 2017")))

Comment: What's your objection to using `=YEAR(M2)`?

Comment: Please note that *YEAR(2017)* is **1905**

Comment: Sorry, I was going to write in a formula, but figured it wouldn't work. I think one of my issues is what 'Gary's Student' mentioned.  IF(Year(M2 < 2017) or IF (Year(M2)<2017 - - but I don't know if excel recognizes 2017 as the year.

Comment: What is actually in cell M2?  The [YEAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/year-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9) requires a true date-serial.  So if M2 is just the number 2017, just use the number `=IF(M2<2017,"Before 2017",M2)`

Comment: If M2 contains a text string that looks like a date (but isn't actually a formatted date-serial), then you'll also have problems.  We really need to identify what is actually in cell M2.

Comment: Right now I have M2 formatted as Short Date so looks like 2018-09-30

Comment: I don't see how this is the same as the thread that was linked with the answer.  That thread can show me how the date is formatted, but it doesn't help me with the formula.

Comment: The linked thread explains **why** you are not getting the answer you are looking for and once you understand the concept, the solution should be obvious. Further, it offers the simplest solution which is to simply use `=m2` and format as `yyyy`. It also explains why `year(2017)-year(2016)=0` in some detail. Using `=year(m2)` is your solution if you actually want the hard numbers 2016, 2017, etc.

Comment: In short, you have an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You think there is something wrong with your formula(s) and while, yes there is a problem, the fact that you are going about it in this manner shows you do not understand how dates are used in an Excel worksheet. Grasp that concept first then the correct formula should be obvious.

Comment: *'You had the years as numbers in A1:A2; not as full dates. Using the 1-per-day formula, 1952 is May 5, 1905 and 1953 is May 6, 1905. If you peel out the year of each of those with the YEAR() function, you are subtracting 1905 from 1905; resulting in zero.'*

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(YEAR(M2) = 2017,2017,IF(YEAR(M2) = 2018,2018,IF(YEAR(M2) = 2019,2019, "Before 2017")))
```

or better

```
=IF(YEAR(M2)<2017,"Before 2017",YEAR(M2))
```

Comment: Unfortunately - this did not work =IF(YEAR(M2) = 2017,2017,IF(YEAR(M2) = 2018,2018,IF(YEAR(M2) = 2019,2019, "Before 2017")))

Comment: It's not a huge deal - I can sort and fill, just wanted to learn for the future.

Comment: What is in the M2 cell? If it is a proper date it will work if a text may not

Comment: I have it formatted as Short date

Comment: Is there any chance that you could to send me the file with an example?

Comment: It's a work file, I could create a new file, but I can explain I feel like.  The dates in cell M2 are formatted YYYY,M,D. For example 2018-11-30.  Thank you for your help and sorry I can't send.

Comment: Could you please check the cel M2 by formulas below and let me know the results 
=ISTEXT(M2)
=ISNUMBER(M2)
=LEN(M2)